# Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have an if statement where I want it to be true if two or more conditions = true.  I tried using the && operator but VS2012 just complains stating that;

Error *Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DelegateFolderPermissionLevel'*

I have tried three ways:

```
if (item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor && item.Permissions.InboxFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor)
            {

                item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor;

            }
```

and

```
     if (item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel && item.Permissions.InboxFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor)
            {
                item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor;
            }
```

and

```
if ((item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor) && (item.Permissions.InboxFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor))
            {
                item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor;
            }
```

Could not find anything useful on the net.  How would I go about writing such a statement?  It works fine with just the one condition..

Comment: This does not seem to a duplicate of the question "Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operand of type 'bool' and 'int'", that question relates specifically to operand !>.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting parentheses around each condition:

```
if ((item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor) && 
    (item.Permissions.InboxFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor))
{
    item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mr.p.s.w.g is right it may solve your problem but i am here to tell you what was the problem in your code 
Your first two try

```
if (item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor && item.Permissions.InboxFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor)
```

and

```
if (item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel && item.Permissions.InboxFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor)
```

Fail because you are not aware about precedence order of operators 
use this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx

> compiler interpreter it as **TRUE && item.Permissions.InboxFolderPermissionLevel**

in first case, and same for other one also that's why it give you error

and your third  try

```
if ((item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor) && (item.Permissions.InboxFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor))
```

Operator for first condition will be "==" not "=" :) 
"=" is for vb.net i guess. 
I hope you are clear now 
and your ans will be as given by p.s.w.g

```
 if ((item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor) && 
    (item.Permissions.InboxFolderPermissionLevel != DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor))
{
    item.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor;
}
```